# Debugger does not show my code after a segmentation fault

Tags: qt, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, qt6

I'm using Qt 6.2.0, Qt Crator 5.0.2, Ubuntu 20.04.
I built my Qt application in Debug mode.

I surely made some errors in my code because it fires a segmentation fault.
My problem is I'm not able to find the offending line because the debugger does not show anything useful (at least to me!).

[image]

As you can see in the call stack there are only greyed lines - that means "assembler" code. I tried to inspect all the threads but no one shows my code.

Does this mean I have a wrong setup of the debugger?
If it's fine (it may happen such a scenario) how to find out the exact point that fires the segmentation fault?

I tried to place here and there some `qDebug()` instructions, but it's not so trivial...

Comment: Because the crash is in Qt's own code and caused by the problem not even directly on the stack starting from your code. Some wrong parameters or so passed to Qt object via queued signal-slot or other delayed execution technique. Look at what your animation code does. Try to comment it our completely then try to uncomment partially until you get why exactly it crashes.

Comment: Such issues is the main reason I discourage my students from using QML (far too complicated).

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen a crash from QML. Usually it just throw a warning in the console skipping the offending condition...

Answer (score 1):

try to start the debugger with a breakpoint on the first line of your code in the main.cpp file where QApplication instance is creating. if it doesn't catch therethen the problem is in your debug configuration but if it breaks on the breakpoint then try to step over and step in to see where the problem will raise.

Comment: The debugger works fine. It catch the breakpoints and if I create a crash intentionally (i.e. wrong pointer) it catches it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults happen when somewhere memory not owned by our process (at least not yet owned), is accessed (read or written).

In other words, you pass an invalid pointer somewhere to `Qt`, or you `delete` an object that is still in use by `Qt`.

So the crash happens in `Qt` framework's code, although caused by your code; your screenshot seems to show a `QML-Property` related stacktrace, and you should use it to pinpoint the actual reason (for example, search in stacktrace's variables, and find QML property's name).